# Is it possible to update an iPad 2 to 6.1.6 instead of 7.0.6?

Tags: ios, software-update

We have a (non-jailbroken) test iPad 2 with iOS 6. Following the recent SSL vulnerability patch, we'd like to update it. However, the update I see in iTunes/Settings is to 7.0.6. We'd really like to keep it at 6 (=update to 6.1.6). Is this possible?

Comment: Basically it says that 6.1.6 is not available for iPad 2, which is a big bummer (and just begs the question I asked, because maybe there's way regardless).